# SpriteKit unarchiveFromFile does not load textures from asset catalogues and atlases

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, sprite-kit

I'm still new with SpriteKit, and wanted to see if I can construct a level using Xcode's SKS editor. When i added a couple of sprites with the "Spaceship.png" texture and built the template app, the textures don't load.

Here's a screenshot of the vanilla OSX Game template using Swift as the language, and adding a supplied "Spaceship.png" sprite. The texture shows fine:
[image: Sprite texture shows fine in the SKScene editor]
And here's the result of building and running the app with only that modification to the template:
[image]

The debug console displays this warning message:
[image]
I tried to add an .atlas folder, and got the same result. the scene just displays the red X icon in place of the sprite. If the added sprites where just color sprites, they display fine. I had an app some time ago that I scrapped, where I used to load the SKScene and would manually add the sprite assets within to my SKScene sub-class, and it worked fine.

If, however, i moved the textures - "Spaceship.png" as an example - to the root of the project, i.e. not inside an asset catalogue or .atlas folder, the scene loads with the textures displaying fine.

Here's the texture added to the root of the project:

[image]

And this is the desired result:
[image]
I tried to manually add the loaded assets from the SKS file to the scene via `enumerateChildNodesWithName(_,usingBlock)` and I get the same result if the textures were not in the root of the project folder.

This is me trying to add the assets manually:

```
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    /* Pick a size for the scene */
    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        let sceneToBePresented = GameScene()

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        sceneToBePresented.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        sceneToBePresented.size = scene.size

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        self.skView!.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        self.skView!.showsFPS = true
        self.skView!.showsNodeCount = true
        scene.enumerateChildNodesWithName("*") { node, stop in
            sceneToBePresented.addChild(node.copy() as SKSpriteNode)
        }

        self.skView!.presentScene(sceneToBePresented)
    }
}
```

I looked around SpriteKit classes - `SKNode`, `SKScene`, `SKTexture`, `SKSPriteNode` - for any clue about paths, caching, preloading, or anything but was unable to find a thing that could make this work.

I am running Xcode 6.1.1 and my target is 10.9, and the language I'm using is Swift, although the same behavior holds true using ObjC. Is this a feature or a bug? Anybody else running/ran into a similar situation ?

Thanks in advance for any help

[UPDATE]

Looks like this is not implemented yet - loading textures from asset catalogs - as this post in the dev forums discusses the same issue, and his solution is to rename the asset catalogues to be the same name as the texture. In essence, what I found out about having the image files in the root folder: [How do you load sprite textures from Images.xcassets when using SKS scene file](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/253526?tstart=0), although my earlier app which i managed to roll-back to a working state does load textures from .atlas'es, but i can't seem to do it with a clean template!!!

Comment: Did you try doing a clean then build?
I have had a lot of problems with the scene editor. I really wanted to use it for my game development, but it was just way too buggy and incomplete on features.

Comment: I did. I even started a new clean template from scratch like shown above. the only modification I did was to add a textured sprite to the `GameScene.sks` file. One thing curious, though, an iOS version of the same template works fine, without `SKTexture` warnings. So, I'm starting to think it might be an OSX target issue. Although, it works fine on as low as iOS 7.0. Plus it worked before in an app that I botched, as I was loading sprite assets from an SKS file and adding them manually to my scene without problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Answering my own question here]

As far as I can tell, at this moment, loading texture from asset catalogues - `Images.xcassets` - while unarchiving or deserializing an `SKScene` file does not work on OSX based on my attempts and the devforumns post referenced above.

Loading of the textures from image atlases, however, works by forcing `SKTexture` to load the image. Forcing or 'touch'ing `SKTexture` can be done via the `preloadWithCompletionHandler(_:)` or `preloadTextures(_:, withCompletionHandler:)` methods, or simply by printing the description of the sprite's `SKTexture` as i have discovered.

For the benefit of anybody who might need further assistance, here is a code snippet that preloads the textures after unarchiving an SKS file:

```
if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
    for child in scene.children as [SKNode] {
        if child is SKSpriteNode {
            let sprite = child as SKSpriteNode
            sprite.texture?.preloadWithCompletionHandler({ })
            /* or even a simple debug log of the texture */
            /* println(sprite.texture) */
        }
    }
    /* Do your other stuff ... */
    ...
}
```

If I'm wrong please correct me. Until somebody does, or Apple fixes the discrepancy between SpriteKit's behavior between iOS and OSX, I will not be looking for another solution, and will follow Murphey's law:

> If it works, don't fix it

Answer (score 1):

Follow Salam Horani solution's, for Swift 2.x you dont have yet "unarchiveFromFile" so you can create scene like this:

```
if let gameScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
    // ...
}
```